# Get selected rows of Rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am using rhandsontable in a Shiny App and I would like to know how to use the getSelected() method of Handsontable in this case, as I intend to apply changes on the data.frame.

Answer (score 26):

You can obtain the selected row, column, range, and cell values, as well as the edited cells using selectCallback=TRUE. You can edit a cell by double-clicking on it, and accept the changes by pressing "return" or "enter".

Minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
ui=fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('table'),
  verbatimTextOutput('selected')
)

server=function(input,output,session)({
  df=data.frame(N=c(1:10),L=LETTERS[1:10],M=LETTERS[11:20])
  output$table=renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(df,selectCallback = TRUE,readOnly = FALSE)
  )
  output$selected=renderPrint({
    cat('Selected Row:',input$table_select$select$r)
    cat('\nSelected Column:',input$table_select$select$c)
    cat('\nSelected Cell Value:',
        input$table_select$data[[
          input$table_select$select$r]][[input$table_select$select$c]])
    cat('\nSelected Range: R',input$table_select$select$r,
        'C',input$table_select$select$c,':R',input$table_select$select$r2,
        'C',input$table_select$select$c2,sep="")
    cat('\nChanged Cell Row Column:',input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[1]],
        input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[2]])    
    cat('\nChanged Cell Old Value:',input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[3]])
    cat('\nChanged Cell New Value:',input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[4]])
  })
}) # end server
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Good, thank you. One remark: the two "`+1`" for the cell value should be removed.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks a lot! I had to add a validation to check whether the sum of a column would exceed 100 (and to set the max value of the cell that it could be edited to dynamically). Worked out very well using a reactive function to assign the max value.

Comment: `input$table_select$select$rAll` will return all selected rows. And `cAll` will return all selected columns.

Comment: Is there a way to unselect, so the "Selected Row: " becomes NA again once the row is clicked again or when clicked outside the table? @SeGa

Answer (score 2):

While rhandsontable is a real good implementation of handsontable (credit goes to @jrowen), currently it does not include getSelected().

The event of a user altering any cell (including selecting / deselecting a checkbox) is tracked by shiny. This gives the opportunity to use checkboxes to let the user to select (or de-select) one or more rows.

Unfortunately the logic to understand what has been selected needs to be developed on the server side by your code.

The snippet of code below may give you some idea on how to manage it.

```
options(warn=-1)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

options(warn=-1)
quantity <- id <- 1:20
label <- paste0("lab","-",quantity)
pick <- FALSE
iris_ <- data.frame(id=id,pick=pick, quantity=quantity,label=label,iris[1:20,] ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mtcars_ <- data.frame(id=id,pick=pick, quantity=quantity,label=label,mtcars[1:20,] ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
iris_$Species <- NULL #  i.e.  no factors
#---------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(6,rHandsontableOutput('demTb')),
        column(3,uiOutput("demSli")),
    column(3, radioButtons("inButtn", label=NULL, choices= c("iris","mtcars"), selected = "iris", inline = TRUE))
        )
    )

server <- function(session, input, output) {

selData <- ""


output$demSli <- renderUI({

if(is.null(input$demTb) ) return()

isolate({
df_ <- hot_to_r(input$demTb)
index <- which(df_$pick==T)
if(length(index)==0) return()
labs <- iris_$label[index] 
pages <- "test"
iter <- length(labs)
buttn <- 1
valLabs <- sapply(1:iter, function(i) {
if(is.null(input[[paste0(pages,"d",labs[i],buttn)]] )) {
          0
} else {  as.numeric(input[[paste0(pages,"d",labs[i],buttn)]])  }
}) 
#
toRender <- lapply(1:iter, function(i) {
  sliderInput(inputId = paste0(pages,"d",labs[i],buttn),
              label =  h6(paste0(labs[i],"")),
              min = -100,
              max = 100,
              step = 1,
              value = valLabs[i],
              post="%",
              ticks = FALSE, animate = FALSE)
              })
})
      return(toRender)

})
#--------------------
rds <- reactive({

  # if( is.null(input$demTb) ) {
  if( input$inButtn == "iris") { 
      if(selData == "" | selData == "mtcars") {
         selData <<- "iris"

        return(iris_) # first time for iris
      }
  } else {
      if(selData == "iris" ) {
         selData <<- "mtcars"

        return(mtcars_) # first time for mtcars
      }
    }

df_ <- hot_to_r(input$demTb)
isolate({

index <- which(df_$pick==T) 
if(length(index)==0) return(df_)
labs <- iris_$label[index] 
pages <- "test"
iter <- length(labs)
buttn <- 1
}) # end isolate
valLabs <- sapply(1:iter, function(i) {
    if(is.null(input[[paste0(pages,"d",labs[i],buttn)]] )) {
      0
    } else {  
      as.numeric(input[[paste0(pages,"d",labs[i],buttn)]])/100  
    }
  })

  dft_ <- data.frame(label=labs, multi=valLabs, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  dft_ <- merge(iris_,dft_,by="label", all.x=T)

  dft_$quantity <- sapply(1:length(dft_$quantity), function(z) {
    if( is.na( dft_$multi[z]) ) { 
    dft_$quantity[z]
  } else { iris_$quantity[z]*(1 + dft_$multi[z]) }
})
dft_[with(dft_,order(as.numeric(id))),]
df_[with(df_,order(as.numeric(id))),]

df_$quantity <- df_$quantity
  return(df_)
  }) 


output$demTb  <-  renderRHandsontable({


if(is.null(rds() )) return()

df_ <- rds() 

df_ <- df_[with(df_,order(as.numeric(id))),]

rhandsontable(df_, readOnly = FALSE, rowHeaders= NULL, useTypes= TRUE) %>%
  hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) 


})

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```