# Convert data from rhandsontable object into dataframe in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

I have a rHandsontable table (**rhandsontable package**) and now I am searching a way how to transfer data from the table into a dataframe.
So far I have not found a clear clue how to perfrom this action.
I would be very grateful for the plain and clear example or useful link.

Besides, I have scanned a useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733573/get-selected-rows-of-rhandsontable). It throws a glimpse of light concerning how to manipulate data inside rhandsontable object.

But no explanation about methods used have been found. It looks like a black box testing. It would be nice if you could share some knowledge of this matter (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the `shinysky` [package](https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky), as it uses `Handsontable`, which has `hot.to.df` function that would allow you to convert your datatable into `dataframe`. Below is a minimal example showing what I mean

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinysky)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Initiate your table
  previous <- reactive({head(mtcars)})

  Trigger_orders <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$hotable1)){return(previous())}
    else if(!identical(previous(),input$hotable1)){
      # hot.to.df function will convert your updated table into the dataframe
      as.data.frame(hot.to.df(input$hotable1))
    }
  })
  output$hotable1 <- renderHotable({Trigger_orders()}, readOnly = F)
  # You can see the changes you made
  output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(Trigger_orders())
})

ui <- basicPage(mainPanel(column(6,hotable("hotable1")),column(6,DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'))))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I have used such a script (abstract): print(hot.to.df(input$all_updates$data)). The outcome is null, the object 'all_updates' is rhandsontable item. Is 'hot.to.df' applicable to rhandsontable?

Comment: I have found the solution - the function 'hot_to_r' from rhandsontable package. It converts into dataframe. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have found the way to convert rhandsontable object into dataframe in R.

It seems to be very easy with the function 'hot_to_r' but the overall function description is **poor**.

So look up some examples and explanations outside the [package description (pdf)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rhandsontable/rhandsontable.pdf) on CRAN. In my case I have used black-box testing.

Here is my case:

```
test_case <- hot_to_r(input$all_updates)
```

The variable 'test_case' is a dataframe.

Comment: Where does this code go? Is there a minimum working example you could post?

Comment: @Matt
what exactly would you like to see? Here is my working script from server side:  
      zzz <- hot_to_r(input$all_updates);
      print(zzz);
      predictor_vector <- rep(predictors,nrow(zzz));
      
      zzz <-cbind(predictor_vector,zzz) ;
      colnames(zzz)[1] <- 'predictor';

Answer (score 0):

I have created a reproducible example here that I used for my existing shiny apps:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  # 1. I assign mtcar df to my rhandsontable ("test_table")
  output$test_table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(mtcars)
  })
  
  # 2. I can make some changes to this rhandsontable and generate the resulting table as dataframe
  values <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  observe({
    values$data <- hot_to_r(input$test_table)
  })

  # 3. I assign this df to a variable call df1
  df1 <- reactive({
    values$data
  })
  
  # 4. Click on action button to see df
  observeEvent(input$print_df_btn, {
    print(df1())
  })
  
})

ui <- basicPage(
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("test_table"),
    br(),
    actionButton("print_df_btn", "Print dataframe to console")
    )
  )

shinyApp(ui, server)
```